# Connecting Multiple Azure Repos to Visual Studio Mac

Tags: git, azure-devops, visual-studio-mac

I want to connect the company's Azure Repos onto my VS for mac. On windows you can connect all the repos by connecting the account, this allows you to be able to search between the repos and select them to clone onto the pc.

I've been trying to search to do this on the mac but only been successful in connecting 1 repo at a time, this isn't very efficient and I just wanted to know how/if this is possible? Any help would be great!

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/report-a-problem?view=vsmac-2019 Nothing you can do here, but report it to Microsoft.

Comment: @LexLi Is this due to it not being a feature?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Anyway, Microsoft promises to bring VS for Windows Git experience to VS for Mac in 2022 release, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022/#refreshing-visual-studio-for-mac so you might wait and see if that fills the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Visual Studio on Windows, Visual Studio for Mac does not have the **`Team Explorer`** that allows you to connect to a team project from Azure DevOps. You can only connect a single repository at a time Visual Studio for Mac.

If you really need this feature on Visual Studio for Mac, I recommend that you can report a feature request on [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=41&entry=suggestion).
That will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product team, and make it more convenient for the product team to collect and categorize your suggestions.